# PHP code to find an IP location from the IP entered through a input box

Tags: php, location, ip

I need to make a custom code which will help me to find location of a particular IP entered through a text box. 
When I searched the internet what I found is only providing automatic detection of IP and it's location. Please help me.

Comment: You're searching bad. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609083/php-ip-location?rq=1

Comment: Why you people are not understanding my question. What I need is a location corresponding to an IP address inputted in an input box (text box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code in my website

Please try it yourself -

```
<?php
function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
{
    $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=5cfaab6c5af420b7b0f88d289571b990763e37b66761b2f053246f9db07ca913&ip=$ipAddr&format=json";
    $d = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($d , true);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
   $ip=countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);

   //print_r($ip);
   echo $ip['cityName'];
}
?>


<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

please use **print_r($ip);** to get the details which parameter will get from the url.

Comment: This code is not working. Can you combine the whole code as one and paste it here.

Comment: This is my complet code please copy and paste in your page.

Comment: Its working thanks, I already figured it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any other code which can provide details like, country, area code, currency, longitude, latitude, time zones etc.

Comment: Yes but i need to help google to findout the related code.

Comment: Hello please download file http://www.ip2location.com/downloads/ip2location-php-6.0.0.zip    and read the developer document http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php

Comment: Chinmay Sahu, can you help me with showing google maps from the ip entered in the above code.

Comment: In above code returns the address then put this address in your dynamic location map parameter url. Thanks.

Comment: can you paste a code for that, I am not that good with coding.  Chinmay Sahu

Comment: Follow the **http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MaxMind GeoIP database. A tutorial for that one can be found at http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/geoip-country-lookup-with-php. There are various other databases available as well. For that take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=geolocation+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: That is about getting location from an automatically detected IP. But what I need is to input an IP in a text box and to find the location for that particular IP.