# I want to find current location of user in php

Tags: php, geolocation, google-api

i am using http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=115.119.253.90&full=true
this api for getting current location but when this site goes down i am not able to get current location.

can google provide any api to find current location using ip.

Comment: You obviously know from your post that your end goal is to find a secondary location API, yet you show absolutely no effort.  So basically you want us to google this for you?  -1

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a good PHP geolocation service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724971/is-there-a-good-php-geolocation-service)

Comment: @Corbin WTH? He doesn't want you to google it for him.  He's asking if there's a google API for getting location using IP.  It's a question.

Comment: @Jack Oh no, I understood his question.  Just he is capable of googling "google geolocation api" by himself.  "can google provide any api to find current location using ip" is not exactly a difficult question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use the HTML5 [Geolocoation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), you can detect a bit from IP.

Or try other other solution

[The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

[Geolocator-PHP](http://freecode.com/projects/ipgeolocation-php-class)

[Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

[ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.