# My location without geocoding

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a map with clusters and I need to get location without using [*The Google Geocoding API*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). All i need is some code or link to help to make automatic generation location (or atleast town I'm in) without any popups, so I could get coodinates from google api.

Comment: You know that [GeoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is from the google API ? So you're contradicting yourself. Also what do you mean by `automatic generation location (or atleast town I'm in) without any popups`. Your question is unclear and lacks code.

Comment: When you are using GeoCoding a prompt (i guess it's called like that) is shown where you have to agree to share your location. I need something that does not need such confirmation

Comment: @MV If you want *accurate* information, there's no real way around that. If you don't particularly care about accuracy, geolocation-by-IP is not a bad substitute.

Comment: Well there is a reason behind that:privacy. Unless you want to use an exploit to bypass it there is only another solution: determine the location by the IP address, this isn't accurate.

Comment: If you don't want that pop-up, then you either need to crack a browser to break its security; or some form of wireless tag (such as those used for pet tracking).... either way, it's akin to spying

Comment: I've found such link - freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10562353/1239506

Comment: These comments are amazing.

Comment: @Jazza not only amazing but also true :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the [geoip extension](http://pecl.php.net/geoip) or [Net_GeoIP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP) from PEAR to detect the approximate location of the user by their IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this service on http://www.maxmind.com/en/home. They have a nice api. good luck