# How to redirect to sub knowing the ip

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ip

Hello I'm trying to make redirections in wordpress for example if I have ip starting on 73.... I want to redirect to subpage. How and where can I do it? I have to use .htaccess file?

Comment: what ip are you referring to ?

Comment: I will have diffrent ip from diffrent cities and If I have ip from London I want to redirect to subpage for London.

Comment: its called geolocation, not very reliable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562265/i-want-to-find-current-location-of-user-in-php/ (and many more)

Comment: This might help: http://www.wpjedi.com/geo-redirect-wordpress-plugins-for-geo-targeting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is basic and will work sometimes, but users can spoof their IP address if they want to.

```
$userIp = explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (($userIp[0].'.'.$userIp[1].'.'.$userIp[2]) == '192.168.2') 
{
header("location:sub.domain.com");
}
```

Comment: Can I determine the pool of addresses?

Comment: Let me edit for what I think you want.

Comment: the start of the ip string is the least usefull part.

Comment: Well I didn't expect you to be looking for 192 IP ranges either...  It's not hard to finish from here.

Comment: I'm not looking for 192 IP but you helped me at all thank you very much :)

Comment: See edit again, you can see how to add more than one to find different ranges.

Comment: Also, if you start getting crazy, a switch would be much more easy to follow than if statements.