# Finding the nearest town/city

Tags: php, location

I am looking for a way to find the nearest town/city and the county of the person browsing my website. Then I would like it to be something like:

```
$town = "London, England";
```

Or something like:

```
$town = "Bacup, Lancashire GB";
```

Google has managed to do something like this. When you search something, at the bottom of the page it says "Your village - from your internet address".

Thanks

Comment: Why? What's your reason?

Comment: What you're most likely after is something called "[geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation)"


Gogle has an API that will do it for you. There's snippets and libraries ready made for php, html and jquery if thats what you mean


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724971/is-there-a-good-php-geolocation-service may be relevant


http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

http://html5demos.com/geo

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

beware: modern browsers will ask for user permission before trying to get geolocation.

Comment: Yeah, that will be fine if it needs permission. If the user is browsing on a mobile/tablet device that has GPS, does it automatically use that? @TheGeorgeL

Comment: it will ask for permission on mobile too. which in most cases will freak the user out about privacy and make them close the tab.

Comment: what you doing it for anyhow?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know the location of the person viewing your website, the data will be taken from the client machine.
Use

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

for getting the client's location. The *showPosition* is a function name to be passed, so define a function with this name. If you just want to show the location only on client machine, do as follows:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```

Or you can send data to your server too.

You can get a little more information about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Now you have the coordinates ( find out, how accurate? ), use google map location services api to get the location name. 
The Google Maps Geolocation API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Comment: For Chrome 5.0+, IE 9.0+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 5.0+ and Opera 16.0+

so make sure you put in validation, something like:
`if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}`